# Receiving error: Exception thrown at 0x009B1396 in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x009BA000. on my assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am working on a low level programming project & am having trouble getting past this error when debugging: "Exception thrown at 0x009B1396 in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x009BA000." which occurs on line 47. I am trying to make matrices given the two user inputted values. Any & All help would be appreciated!
Code:

```
INCLUDE <C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc>
INCLUDELIB <C:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib>


.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
FirstDimension dword ?
SecondDimension dword ?

prompt1 BYTE "Please enter first positive integer 1 - 9: ", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Please enter second positive integer 1 - 9: ", 0

m1 dword ?
m2 dword ?
mp dword ?

ranNum dword ?

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET prompt1                 ; part a
call WriteString                   ; user input
mov edx, OFFSET firstDimension
call ReadInt

mov edx, OFFSET prompt2                 ; part b
call WriteString                   ; user input
mov edx, OFFSET secondDimension
call ReadInt


mov eax, FirstDimension                          ; part c
mul SecondDimension
mov eax, OFFSET m1

mov eax, 15                   ; part d
call RandomRange         ; retrieving random number 0 - 15
mov ranNum, eax          ; storing it in eax
mov eax, (black * 16) + red        ; bonus points
call SetTextColor
call DumpMem             ; part e

mov ebx, SecondDimension      ; part f ** error occurs**
mul FirstDimension
mov ebx, OFFSET m2   

mov ebx, 15              ; part g
call RandomRange         ; retrieving random number 1 - 15
mov ranNum, ebx          ; storing it in ebx
mov ebx, (black * 16) + blue       ; bonus points
call SetTextColor
call DumpMem            ; part h

mov eax, OFFSET mp            ; part i
mov eax, FirstDimension
mul FirstDimension
mov eax, 0              ; part j
mov eax, (black * 16) + green      ; bonus points
call SetTextColor
call DumpMem            ; part k

mov eax, OFFSET mp       ; part l   
mov eax, SecondDimension
mul firstDimension
add ebx, eax
call WriteStackFrame          ; part m



Invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

I tried pushing & popping the registers but I do not think I was doing it correctly if that is what I should do. I am not very experienced in this field & am clearly struggle.

Comment: It's very unlikely that `mov ebx, SecondDimension      ; part f ** error occurs**` could actually be the faulting instruction.  That's loading from space you reserved in `.data`, with an address generated by the linker.  An earlier `mul SecondDimension` doesn't fault, and you don't make any VirtualProtect or VirtualAlloc system calls that could make that memory unreadable or make the code writeable so the address could get messed up in the machine code.  (I'm not sure why you do the earlier `mul`; you overwrite the EAX part of the product right away, leaving only the EDX high half, prob. zero)

Comment: I'd be more worried about `call DumpMem`; that's probably the only part of your code that's using a pointer.  But a pointer to what?  https://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/source/irvinelib/dumpmem.htm says it takes args in ESI, ECX, and EBX to indicate the start, length, and element-size of the dump.  But your program doesn't set ESI anywhere.  Oh, your first `call DumpMem` is right before the instruction you said had the problem.  Probably your debugger showed confusing output about an eventual return address from a function that faulted before it returned.

Comment: ok, thanks! so which registers should i be using before the call DumpMem? i guess i am just confused as to how to get through this violation.

Comment: I linked the docs for it in my last comment.  That tells you which arg goes in which register, and what they mean.